# Using c++ random number generators in a pure fashion

Tags: c++, random, std

I have a monte-carlo like system, where I have some state the evolves randomly, using an internal random number generator. I'm also storing a `const` copy of this state elsewhere in the program, as I would like to know how it would evolve, were it to actually evolve. This requires 2 things of the random number generator:

1) The ability to clone the generator without modifying it, to store in the copied version of the state.

2) The ability to determine what the next random number would be from the `const` copy of the generator.

Is this possible using only the standard library? If not, can you recommend a 3rd party library?

Answer (score 3):

The standard [C++11 random generators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) are ordinary objects that can be copied, and copies will produce identical sequences.  They can also serialize and deserialize their internal state into iostreams using `operator<<` and `operator>>`.

The `operator()` that generates random numbers is not a `const` function, since it changes the generator's internal state.  So you can't call it directly on a `const` copy of the generator.  But you could make a temporary mutable copy of the `const` one, generate a value from it, and then destroy it.

If your compiler doesn't support C++11, you can use the [Boost.Random library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_random.html), which was the basis for the standard one.

Comment: With the exception of `std::random_device`, which can be either pseudo RNG or true random device, e.g. using quantum effect random on modern cpu. With such non-deterministic RNG the sequence of the copy may likely be different.

Comment: @Calvin, well, that class is non-copyable, so it'd quickly become clear at compile time that you can't make deterministic copies.  But yeah, I should've mentioned it as a caveat.